# Woocommerce variations with select2 conflict with default selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I have noticed that once I've added select2 to variations in Woocommerce and default variations are set (lets say width and height of a product). 
Then it is impossible to select default option from the select menu, once you select other option and come back to default. It is grayed out.

Looks like there is an error with aria-selected="true" being selected twice (default option has it and it is not removed once new option is selected).

I am initiating select2 with basic setup.

```
jQuery(".woocommerce-ordering select, .variations select, .wcpa_row select").select2({
    width: '100%',
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    }
);
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Try to replace `select2` with [`selectwoo`](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/selectwoo-an-accessible-replacement-for-select2/) which is a fork of select2 used by WooCommerce.

Comment: It's even older project.

Comment: I have the same issue. select2 version 4.0.5 and older work correctly but not any version newer than that. selectwoo is not an option for me as it no longer supports html for styling of your options. ref: https://github.com/woocommerce/selectWoo/issues/39

Comment: I've filed a bug report on github:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/6087